# How to connect to a Lego™ EV3 over USB from a linux machine

Tags: linux, usb, debian, linux-mint, connection

The title is my question. I have a Linux computer from which I would like to access and program the new [Lego™ EV3](http://www.lego.com/mindstorms/about-ev3).

Also if there are any resources on how to program the Lego™ EV3 with C++ I would like to know. Note that I do not have a SD card. So using ev3dev is kinda hard.

I have a LMDE machine (Linux Mint Debian Edition) which just works like a Debian one.

Comment: A link to said "EV3" might be handy

Comment: @JourneymanGeek here it is!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Java not sure about C++
you can try scratchx you can work on the website and save your work on your hdd.

note I didn't try it myself on linux it's just some idea...

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for trying to help on this question.  The site's Q&A model reserves answers for solutions to the question (the "how" in the title).  Just tossing out vague directions for the user to explore isn't really a solution.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post comments, which are the right way to post helpful suggestions.